# How to multiply a query column by a cell refference on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

Below is the query that I use, and it works:

```
=QUERY(Input!A2:I33;
 "SELECT '000', A, B, C, D, E, ' ', F, '  ', '   ', '    ', G, '     ', '      ', '       ', '"&TEXT(Input!L8;"dd/mm/yyyy")&"', 0.6*H 
  WHERE I='I' 
  LABEL '000' '', ' ' '', '  ' '', '   ' '', '    ' '', '     ' '', '      ' '', '       ' '', '"&TEXT(Input!L8;"dd/mm/yyyy")&"' '', 0.6*H ''")
```

My question is: How can I multiply H by a cell refference? For instance, here's what I tried, but it did not work ("Input!L9" reffers to a cell with the value 0.6):

```
=QUERY(Input!A2:I33;
 "SELECT '000', A, B, C, D, E, ' ', F, ' ', ' ', ' ', G, ' ', ' ', ' ', '"&TEXT(Input!L8;"dd/mm/yyyy")&"', "&Input!L9&"*H 
  WHERE I='I' 
  LABEL '000' '', ' ' '', ' ' '', ' ' '', ' ' '', ' ' '', ' ' '', ' ' '', '"&TEXT(Input!L8;"dd/mm/yyyy")&"' '', "&Input!L9&"*H ''")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- try **`H*"&Input!L9&"`** with label **`H*"&Input!L9&"''`**

```
=QUERY(Input!A2:I33,
 "select '000',A,B,C,D,E,' ',F,'  ','   ','    ',G,'     ','      ','       ','"&TEXT(Input!L8,"dd/mm/yyyy")&"',H*"&Input!L9&" 
  where I='I' 
  label '000''',' ''','  ''','   ''','    ''','     ''','      ''','       ''','"&TEXT(Input!L8,"dd/mm/yyyy")&"''',H*"&Input!L9&"''")
```

[image]

**note:** EU syntax will need to have **`SUBSTITUTE(Input!L9; ","; ".")`** instead of **`Input!L9`**

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I tried running your code, but I recieved a #VALUE! error:
https://imgur.com/a/LKBA3ks

Comment: @PauloRuzanovsky from your picture I can see that you are using different locale... what number is in your L9 cell? 0.6? should be 0,6 in your case

Comment: I was aware, the number on L9 was 0,6. I believe the query doesn't understand diferent separators, since I swaped to united states locale and it worked with the dot separator. If you know how to make it work with the comma separator, let me know

Here is the copy spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1znYM6xvToM3pwTdwN2Ow2ND3MVxDBZA7VU2P5ugirXA/edit#gid=1900256196

Comment: @PauloRuzanovsky done. check your sheet

Comment: Thank you! It definetely solves.